# How to inject custom services from DbContextFactory class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to inject `ICurrentUserService`  and `IDateTime` services in the `DbContext` class as:

```
public class BookDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;

    public BookDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }

    public BookDbContext(DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions,
        ICurrentUserService currentUserService,
        IDateTime dateTime) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<AuditableEntity> entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedBy = "b2c3196c-fbe7-473d-9a0f-b491f2918a6c";/// _currentUserService.UserId;
                    entry.Entity.Created = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.LastModifiedBy = _currentUserService.UserId;
                    entry.Entity.LastModified = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;
            }
        }

        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return result;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And i am implementing the `DBContextFactory` class as:

```
public class DBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BookDbContext>
{
    public BookDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BookDbContext>();
        var connectionString =
            configuration.GetConnectionString("BookStoreDbConnection");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new BookDbContext(builder.Options, new OperationalStoreOptionsMigrations());

    }
}
public class OperationalStoreOptionsMigrations : IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions>
{
    public OperationalStoreOptions Value => new OperationalStoreOptions()
    {
        DeviceFlowCodes = new TableConfiguration("DeviceCodes"),
        EnableTokenCleanup = false,
        PersistedGrants = new TableConfiguration("PersistedGrants"),
        TokenCleanupBatchSize = 100,
        TokenCleanupInterval = 3600,
    };
}
```

Implementation of `ICurrentUserService`, which is in the separate project, where the `Dbcontextfactory` does not have any references.

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public string UserId => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    }
```

However, I am stuck on how to pass the other parameter that is: `ICurrentUserService` and `IDateTime` during the run-time.

With my current implementation of `DbContext` class, the other services that have not been injected from `DbContextFactory` are getting null.

What could be the alternative workaround for this situation?

Comment: Implementation of `ICurrentUserService` interface has direct or indirect access to DbContext?

Comment: No, they do not access any member of DbContext.

Comment: That's almost exactly a problem I faced this week.... To play nicely with DI, call `this.GetService<IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions>>()` etc, in the constructor instead of adding a constructor argument.

Comment: Implementation of other services like `ICurrentUserService` and `IDateTime` are not available in the project where `DbContext` lies. So, how to use those services?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question/request correctly, then basically you are trying to set the CreatedBy and Created properties when you call SaveChanges() when you add an entity or ModifiedBy and Modified when you are updating an entity.

Personally, I feel that you may be overcomplicating this and you would save your self a lot of trouble by just setting the CreatedBy and Created properties when adding or ModifiedBy and Modified when being updated. I would leave the DbContext alone and implement the Facade pattern so you can inject those additional services into the constructor or add parameters to the SaveAsync() method.

For example:

The implementation below would be registered as a scoped open generic service that could be injected anywhere, OTHER than another service that is registered as a singleton. Otherwise, you will get a runtime exception informing you that you cannot inject a Scoped service into a Singleton due to captured dependencies.

First your check to see if there is already an entity with the same Id in the database. If no entity is found then you are creating and entity, else you are updating an existing one.

```cs
    ///Register with Dependency Injection
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddScoped(typeof(IFacadeService<>), typeof(FacadeService<>));
    }

    ///IFacadeService implementation
    public interface IFacadeService<T> where T : EntityBase
    {
         Task<int> SaveAsync(T Entity);

         ///Other methods removed for brevity
    }

    public class FacadeService<T> : IFacadeService<T> where T : EntityBase
    {
        readonly DbContext ctx;
        readonly DbSet<T> Dbset;
        readonly IUserContext userContext;
        readonly ICurrentDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider;        

        public FacadeService(
                DbContext ctx,
                IUserContext userContext,
                ICurrentDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider)
        {
            this.ctx = ctx;
            Dbset = ctx.Set<T>();
            this.userContext= userContext;
            this.dateTimeProvider= dateTimeProvider;
        }

        public async Task<int> SaveAsync(T Entity)
        {
            var e = await Dbset
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstAsync(a => a.Id.Equals(Entity.Id));

            if(e == null)
            {
                Entity.CreatedByUserId = userContext.CurrentUserId;
                Entity.ModifiedByUserId = userContext.CurrentUserId;
                Entity.CreatedDate = dateTimeProvider.CurrentDateTimeUTC;
                Entity.ModifiedDate = dateTimeProvider.CurrentDateTimeUTC;

                ctx.Add(Entity);
            }
            else
            {
                Entity.ModifiedByUserId = userContext.CurrentUserId;
                Entity.ModifiedDate = dateTimeProvider.CurrentDateTimeUTC;

                ctx.Update(Entity);
            }

            return ctx.SaveChanges();
        }     
    }
```

**Edited from Repository to Facade.

Comment: So, you suggest using a generic repository instead?

Comment: I would. It is soo much easier to implement and change functionality. This is a very common pattern that is used and when you look at this a little more you will see that, when it comes to mutations, there are really only two methods you will need, Save and Delete. If you are performing soft deletes then you only need the Save method. Additionally, in some projects where the Save method was a little more involved, I seperated that out into its own interface, ISave that was injected into the repository.

Comment: Please **do not** suggest using a generic repository pattern with EF. Why? Because entity framework is **already** an implementation of both the generic repository *and* unit of work design patterns. There is absolutely zero reason to double abstract it, except of course if your goal is to make things harder on yourself

Comment: My bad...the term Repository implies more than what I would like it to in this context. So, we will call it a facade service that wraps the implementation you need into a simplified interface.   [Facade Pattern Explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)